# How to synchronize SQL Server databases without Entity Framework in .Net 6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization

I have 2 SQL Server databases on different instances.

Server 1:

Table `employee`:

```
Name, address , phone
```

Server 2 (with different names):

Table `x_employee`:

```
x_Name, x_address, x_phone
```

My project uses `System.Data.SqlClient` and I cannot use Entity Framework for business reasons - because the database belongs to another project as well and we cannot risk a migration changing tables in that database.

If it was with EF, things would have been easy but without EF, this seems to be a lot of work. I have also found these libraries but they seem to be old and lack support:

https://codemag.com/Article/1905081/Synchronizing-Databases-Using-Microsoft-Sync-Framework

https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Which one shall be the leading database?

Comment: @Fildor We must take data from server 2 and insert it into server 1.

Comment: In the past, I had a central DB with master reference data as well as appointments for remote workers with intermittent connectivity. A stored procedure would take a timestamp from a handheld device and select changed table information from central DB and return this as one giant DataSet. The device simply loaded the local database as a DataSet and called the Merge method with the retrieved DataSet. This synchronized data for the specific worker. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.merge?view=net-7.0#system-data-dataset-merge(system-data-dataset-system-boolean)